# Relational SQL query array DB::table()-> select() ->where()->get(); [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got an error with this code and the error is just from  `'verification'< 25` The "less than" operator is the issue when I change that with `=>` it does not come up with an error. How do I rewrite this query?

```
$allRecords = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(name, " ", last_name) AS name'),'email as email_address')->where(array('verification'< 25,'is_admin'=>0,'is_approved'=>1))->orderby('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: try this 'verification<' and let me know please?

Comment: You mean  'verification<' => 25 or just  'verification<' 25?

Comment: just 'verification<' 25

Comment: Still getting errors

Comment: The error is coming from PHP or MySQL?

Comment: The error is coming from MySQL

Comment: Solved it, I just used ['verification','<', 25]

Comment: Great, you can accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

```
$allRecords = DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(name, " ", last_name) AS name'),'email as email_address')
                 ->where('verification', '<', 25)
                 ->where(array('is_admin'=>0,'is_approved'=>1))
                 ->orderby('id', 'DESC')
                 ->get();
```